# Twitter Typeahead moves input field

Tags: html, typeahead.js, twitter-typeahead

I just implemented twitter typeahead into my website. I am using bootstrap in this website. I have input fields and once I added the titter typeahead code it moved the input field.

(I know this question has already been asked but he didn't provide code so no answers were given)

[image: What it looks like atm]

[image: What I want it to look like (what is supposed to look like)]

I used the code from the example page (changed the class names and stuff)

```
var substringMatcher = function(strs) {
return function findMatches(q, cb) {
var matches, substringRegex;

// an array that will be populated with substring matches
matches = [];

// regex used to determine if a string contains the substring `q`
substrRegex = new RegExp(q, 'i');

// iterate through the pool of strings and for any string that
// contains the substring `q`, add it to the `matches` array
$.each(strs, function(i, str) {
  if (substrRegex.test(str)) {
    matches.push(str);
  }
});
    cb(matches);
  };
};

var states = (My data)

$('#the-basics .typeahead').typeahead({
   hint: true,
   highlight: true,
   minLength: 1
 },
 {
 name: 'states',
 source: substringMatcher(states)
 });
```

twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/